# Streaming 1080p 30FPS from i.MX to X86 Laptop with Minimum Latency

Tags: linux, arm, video-streaming, gstreamer, low-latency

UVC Camera is used supporting MJPG: 1080p@30 / 720p@30 or YUV:1080p@6 / 720p@6.

**HW Setup-i.MX6 Board [HS-O]:**

**Video Source (VS-O)**: UVC Camera connected with i.MX6 Board USB 2.0 port.

**Video Receive (VR):** X86 Laptop

**Scenario-MJPG:**
VS-O: Capture MJPG stream from UVC for 1080@30
Send MJPG stream to VR over WiFi (RTP)

**Video Receiver:**
Receive MJPG video stream over WiFi (RTP)
Decode MJPG (1080@30)
Display video with 1080p@30.

**Current status:**
**HS-O:**

- Pipeline - 1 : 1080p30 MJPEG Capture, and file dump is working.
- Pipeline - 2 : capture from UVC and stream to X86. Instead of 1080p30, the stream is of 1080p6. 720p30 is working fine though.

**Pipeline - 1:**

- Transmitter:

```cs
$ gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=1        \
                  ! image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 \
                  ! avimux                                            \
                  ! filesink location=newtest.avi
```

- Receiver:  used VLC to play newtest.avi on X86. Found it of 1080p30.

**Pipeline - 2:**

- Transmitter:

```cs
$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
                 ! video/x-raw \
                 ! jpegenc     \
                 ! jpegparse   \
                 ! rtpjpegpay  \
                 ! udpsink host=192.168.0.103 port=5000
```

- Receiver:

```cs
$ gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 buffer-size=90000 \
                 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG, payload=26, clock-rate=90000 \
                 ! rtpjpegdepay \
                 ! jpegparse     \
                 ! queue          \
                 ! jpegdec         \
                 ! videoconvert     \
                 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false async=false --verbose
```

**Challenge:**

- At i.MX6 Board, able to dump MJPG file having 1080@30.
- But while streaming, it always displays at 6FPS or less, so it seems that it is streaming YUV instead of MJPEG.
- While streaming 720p, same pipeline works at 30FPS.

**We need your help in review Pipeline – 2 which we are hoping to get us 1080p30 on HS-O setup.**

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. Good luck.